# Pandas extracting data in one Dataframe using values from 2 other lookup Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe column that has some string that store values from 2 other Dataframes as shown below:

Sample view of df whose column `col` has the below string.

```
col
Highest Sales was for Mobile Scott
Lowest Returns was for Mobile Phone Steve
Low Returns was for Paul
```

I am trying to extract the value from the above Dataframe such that I create a new column that has the product name (as obtained from `prod_df`) and rep name (as obtained from `sales_rep_df`)

Data in `prod_df` Dataframe

```
prod_df
Laptop
Computer
Mobile
Mobile Phone
```

Data in `sales_rep_df` Dataframe

```
sales_rep_df
Scott
Steve
Paul
```

Expected output

```
col, prod, rep
Highest Sales was for Mobile Scott, Mobile
Lowest Returns was for Mobile Phone Steve, Mobile Phone, Steve
Low Returns was for Paul,,Paul
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) for get first amtched value from list:

```
pat1 = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in prod_df['col'])
pat2 = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in sales_rep_df['col'])
df['prod'] = df['col'].str.extract('('+ pat1 + ')', expand=False)
df['rep'] = df['col'].str.extract('('+ pat2 + ')', expand=False)
```

Or [`Series.str.findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) with [`Series.str.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html) for all matches:

```
df['prod'] = df['col'].str.findall(pat1).str.join(',')
df['rep'] = df['col'].str.findall(pat2).str.join(',')
```